# Atualizar modal ao excluir registro da tabela - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Possuo este modal, e tenho a função excluir, preciso que o dado seja excluído e a atualizado, sem fechar o modal.
Segue como está o código:
Este é o modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Fornecedores Vinculados</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fornecedores</th>
                            <th style="text-align:right"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAdd" title="Adicionar Novo Fornecedor" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosFornecedores)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="ExluirItem(@item.Id);" title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui é a função excluir:

```
 function ExluirItem(idItem) {
    var url = "/Produto/ExcluirItens";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { id: idItem },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado) {
                var linha = "#tr" + idItem;
                $(linha).fadeOut(500);
                //location.reload();
                abreModal();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

E aqui o controller de excluir:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExcluirItens(int id)
    {
        var result = false;
        var item = db.ProdutosFornecedores.Find(id);

        if (item != null)
        {
            db.ProdutosFornecedores.Remove(item);
            db.SaveChanges();

            result = true;
        }

        return Json(new { Resultado = result });
    }
```

Como posso fazer para que seja atualizado, sem fechar o modal, ou atualizar a página?

Esta é a função abreModal()

```
  function abreModal() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: O que quer atualizar exatamente?

Comment: Quero atualizar a tabela, ele exclui, mas a linha ainda permanece até realizar o reload da página, eu preciso que ao clicar no ícone de excluir, além de excluir que ele já esta fazendo, que ele retire a linha da tabela.

Comment: Será que não é porque você está usando `onclick`? Já tentou atribuir o evento diretamente pelo jQuery? Eu colocaria uma classe no link de exclusão, criaria um `data-id` nesse link e atribuiria o valor via jQuery. A dúvida agora é: A exclusão é processada?

Comment: Sim,a exclusão é processada, perfeitamente, só que não atualiza no modal, eu tentei atualizar ,e abrir o modal, porém ele atualiza mas não abre o modal.

Comment: Respondi. Acho que achei o erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que encontrei o erro.

Você tem essa definição para o `tr` repetindo no `foreach`

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosFornecedores)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
                <td align="right">
                    <a href="#" onclick="ExluirItem(@item.Id);" title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</tbody>
```

E no jQuery tem isso:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { id: idItem },
    datatype: "json",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.resultado) {
            var linha = "#tr" + idItem;
            $(linha).fadeOut(500);
            //location.reload();
            abreModal();
        }
    }
})
```

Você está tentando pegar um `id` com o valor `#tr + id`, porém esse `id` não foi definido em lugar nenhum na sua `tr`.

Talvez algo assim resolva:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosFornecedores)
        {
            <tr id="tr@item.id">
                <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
                <td align="right">
                    <a href="#" onclick="ExluirItem(@item.Id);" title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</tbody>
```

Não conheço a sintaxe do ASP NET CORE, mas a inteção acima é você definir o `id` da `tr` de acordo com o `id` de `item`.

**Observação**: Tem um typo na sua função. Ao invés de `ExluirItem`, deveria ser `ExcluirItem`.

Comment: Ele atualiza, porém o modal não fica aberto, como posso fazer, para ele atualizar e abrir o modal, ou atualizar somente o modal ?

Comment: Na sua pergunta não tem nenhum código que abre o modal. Poderia adicionar a função `abreModal` a sua pergunta, pra eu dar uma olhada?

Comment: Adicionei a pergunta.

Comment: O modal `#myModal` tá fechando quando exclui?

Comment: Sim, quando eu excluo ele fecha.

Comment: Se eu tiro o reload, ele não fecha, mas também não atualiza a tabela, e se eu coloco o reload, e logo chamo a função abreModal, ele atualiza e não abre o modal.

Comment: @marianac_costa já tentou chamar a função `abreModal` pelo console pra ver o que acontece?

Comment: Ela abre, acabei de fazer o teste

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81271/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-marianac-costa).